Problem of ambiguity in WPF .NET 8 project when using WindowsForms globally
I'm working on a WPF .NET 8 project and the problem started when I wanted to show my application icon in the notification area menu. In WPF it seems that it can't be used directly, you need to enable WindowsForms to use this feature. So I put this in my .csproj project file, to enable WindowsForms:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>ExampleName</RootNamespace>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>

...
Everything works as expected and I was able to use WindowsForms' NotifyIcon without problems. However, when I wanted to use basic controls like TextBox in a window's .cs file, I had to explicitly call the TextBox from System.Windows.Controls.TextBox, because otherwise there would be ambiguity between System.Windows and System.Windows.Forms.
Where is the problem, you might ask, if you can call it explicitly as you said and problem solved. Yes, but there is a problem and that is that in files where I don't use WindowsForms at all I still have to explicitly call the controls because it keeps detecting ambiguity. That's why I would have to change files one by one to call those controls explicitly. Resulting in unnecessary work and readability issues.
Sorry if this is a stupid question but I've really searched for ways and I don't know what to do, thank you.
I've tried using aliases for the amounts, even if Windows Forms wasn't used in that file, but it still didn't work.
using WinForms = winforms.System.Windows.Forms;
I've also tried using the #if preprocessor to include Windows Forms-related code only when USE_WINFORMS is defined, like this:
#define USE_WINFORMS

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

#if USE_WINFORMS
using System.Windows.Forms;
#endif

namespace ExampleName.Windows
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private NotifyIcon notifyIcon;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            #if USE_WINFORMS
            // Código relacionado con NotifyIcon
            var iconStream = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(
                new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/exaple_icon.ico")).Stream;
            var icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);
            notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon
            {
                Icon = icon,
                Visible = true,
                Text = "Black Raven"
            };

            notifyIcon.Click += (s, e) => MostrarVentana();
            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
            #endif
        }

...

You have ImplicitUsings enabled...

you right, I didn´t know that function
